# Total duration not get in player using MP3 url when we pass header in 'react-native-track-player' in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using "react-native-track-player" for playing MP3 url in react native. But when I pass header authenticate at that time I am not able to get whole time of the MP3 url. In my screen it is necessary to show whole time of the url before player load. And also I am not able to do forward and backward action using "seekTO". for trackplayer the code is below,

```
 var list = [currentItem].map(item => Object.assign(item,
    {
      artist: 'tootak',
      headers: { Authorization: Global.authenticateUser },
      url: item.is_local ?
        ('file://' + (item.url ? item.url : (item.URL ? item.URL : '')))
        : Global.getMediaLink(item.url ? item.url : (item.URL ? item.URL : '')),
      id: item.code,
      artwork: Global.getUrl(item.images),
    }))

await TrackPlayer.reset()
await TrackPlayer.add(list)
```

and for to seekTo ,

```
var time = await TrackPlayer.getposition()
await TrackPlayer.seekTo(time + 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

They have referred to it in the docs that the library is only for streaming audio directly and to not depend on it to get something like duration.

> ***react-native-track-player is a streaming library, which means it slowly buffers the track and doesn’t know exactly when it ends. The duration returned by this function is determined through various tricks and may not be exact or may not be available at all.
> You should not trust this function. You should retrieve the duration from a database and feed it to the duration parameter in the Track Object.***

We would need to use something like FFprobe or FFmpeg as a stream analyzer to retrieve the values. There is a package called [get-audio-duration](https://github.com/caffco/get-audio-duration) which does the job for you.